# how to build another admin account of magento to read orders only but can't delete and edit it?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, user

I want to set another admin account of magento that can view order but can't delete and edit. I only choose the role resources(sales>>orders>>Action>>view),but the role still have delete permission. How can I do ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you found solutiion?

Answer (score 1):

What @Siarhey is telling is absolutely right.

You are using an extension. please check under `app/etc/modules` and see what and all modules are installed. if possible please update the question with list of file names present in `app/etc/modules`. we will try to find out which module is reason for "Delete option" .

If you don't have file access, check under

```
system > COnfiguration > Adavanced > Advanced > Disble module output
```

you can see list of modules. please post screen shot of that.

Answer (score 0):

By default the order can not be deleted by the admin. It means that you are using some kind of the third party extension and that extension has no ACL. Try to contact this extension's support team.